# Why do I need "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining" in my setup using "@babel/preset-env" and "@babel/preset-typescript"

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a project using Typescript and @babel/preset-env. Bundling with Webpack fails with this error and the config below.

If I un-comment the line, which forces `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` to be included, then compilation works. It also works if I add Safari, Edge or IE 11 to the `targets` string.

Why is that?

```
ERROR in ./src/bla.ts 58:23
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (58:23)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
>       if (foo?.bar === undefined) {
```

```js
// webpack.config

const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: [path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.ts")],
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Test",
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    alias: {
      lib: path.join(__dirname, "src", "lib"),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              esModule: true,
            },
          },
          "css-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                {
                  modules: false,
                  corejs: 3,
                  useBuiltIns: "usage",
                  include: [
                    // "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining", // parsing fails on optional operator without this
                  ],
                  targets: "last 2 Chrome versions, last 2 Firefox versions",
                },
              ],
              "@babel/preset-typescript",
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The JS parser in Webpack 4 doesn't support optional chaining. With `targets:"last 2 Chrome versions, last 2 Firefox versions"` the code is left untransformed by babel-loader (because those targets support it) so Webpack fails to parse it. Changing `targets` as you mentioned has the same effect as manually including `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`, that is, babel-loader transforms the code before Webpack can choke on it.

related: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10227

According to that issue, Webpack 5 will use an updated parser that will resolve this.